# Unable to run ruby on rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment

I am unable to run ruby on rails application. I setup the database and loaded database schema. When I run:

```
ruby script/server -e production
```

It says:

```
=> Booting Mongrel
=> Rails 2.3.2 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Crtl-C to shutdown server
```

and it just stays there. If I go to the directory where the app is installed, it just lists the directory of files and doesn't run the app. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Have you opened http://localhost:3000/ in a browser?

The '=> Booting Mongrel ...' stuff means the server is running, you just need to navigate a browser to it.

Comment: Yes,but it doesn't load. Is there a way to troubleshoot?

Comment: I must be missing or doing something else wrong, because its just not running for me.

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "it doesn't load"?  Are you just getting a blank page?  Are you getting a page not found?  If you try and load and get the blank page can you view source and see if there are doctype headers?

Comment: If I try to open http://myserver:3000/ in a browser, I just get a 
connection timed out error.

Comment: I can view the directory of files and code in the browser if I just go to myserver/railsapp

Comment: hmm. Are you running this on a virtual host through ssh or something?

Answer (score 0):

You are starting your server in production mode.
Use the development mode fpr debugging, it will give you a better log output.

Run ruby script/server -e development

Comment: When I try it in development mode, I get the following error:

=> Booting Mongrel
=> Rails 2.3.2 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:3000
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql/1-2.7/lib/mysql.so [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.8.7 (2008-06-20 patchlevel 22) [i686-linux]

Comment: This link might help you: http://blogs.sun.com/mandy/entry/segmentation_fault_when_running_rails

Comment: your link is offline... tststs